# How to run code on start of yylex and when token is matched in RE-flex

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, lex

I was using RE-flex to generate a c++ Scanner for a project. I wanted to run code when a token is matched and I followed the Flex way of doing, but that ended up putting the code outside the function. How can I put it at the end, when a token is matched? Also, I want to run code at the beginning of yylex. When I do it the Flex way, it puts the code inside a switch statement based on the start condition. How can I run this code regardless of the start condition? The scanner file is given here.

```
%top {
    #include "driver.h"
    #include "y.tab.hh"
    std::string buffer_2;

    bool actionReturned = false, typeReturned = false, headerReturned;
    int actionCount = 0, typeCount = 0;
%}

%{
    #undef YY_USER_ACTION
%}

%option noyywrap nounput noinput batch debug
%option params="driver &drv"
%x HEADER ACTION TYPE

blank [ \t\r]+
newline \n+
id [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

%{
    #define YY_USER_ACTION loc.columns(yyleng);
%}

%%

    yy::location &loc = drv.location;
    loc.step();
    if(actionReturned) {
        actionReturned = false;
        buffer_2.clear();
        return yy::parser::make_ACTION_CLOSE(loc);
    }
    if(typeReturned) {
        typeReturned = false;
        buffer_2.clear();
        return yy::parser::make_TYPE_CLOSE(loc);
    }
    if(headerReturned) {
        headerReturned = false;
        buffer_2.clear();
        return yy::parser::make_HEADER_CLOSE(loc);
    }

<INITIAL>{blank} loc.step();
<INITIAL>{newline} loc.lines(yyleng); loc.step();
<INITIAL>"%empty" return yy::parser::make_EPSILON(loc);
<INITIAL>"%type" return yy::parser::make_TYPE(loc);
<INITIAL>"%union" return yy::parser::make_UNION(loc);
<INITIAL>"%token" return yy::parser::make_TOKEN(loc);
<INITIAL>"%%" return yy::parser::make_DELIMITER(loc);
<INITIAL>";" return yy::parser::make_SEMICOLON(loc);
<INITIAL>"*" return yy::parser::make_KLEENE_STAR(loc);
<INITIAL>"+" return yy::parser::make_ZERO_MORE(loc);
<INITIAL>"?" return yy::parser::make_OPTIONAL(loc);
<INITIAL>"/" return yy::parser::make_PRODUCTION_OR(loc);
<INITIAL>"<-" return yy::parser::make_RULE_OPEN(loc);
<INITIAL>"%{" BEGIN(HEADER); return yy::parser::make_HEADER_OPEN(loc);
<INITIAL>"<" BEGIN(TYPE); ++typeCount; return yy::parser::make_TYPE_OPEN(loc);
<INITIAL>"{" BEGIN(ACTION); ++actionCount; return yy::parser::make_ACTION_OPEN(loc);
<INITIAL>{id} return yy::parser::make_ID(yytext, loc);
<INITIAL>. {
    throw yy::parser::syntax_error(loc, "Unexpected character: " + std::string(yytext));
}
<INITIAL><<EOF>> return yy::parser::make_YYEOF(loc);

<HEADER>"}" {
loc.step();
    if(buffer_2[buffer_2.length() - 1] == '%') {
        // end has been matched
        buffer_2.pop_back();
        headerReturned = true;
        return yy::parser::make_HEADER_CODE(buffer_2, loc);
    }
    buffer_2 += '}';
}
<HEADER>(.|\n) buffer_2 += yytext[0]; loc.step();

<ACTION>"{" ++actionCount; buffer_2 += '{'; loc.step();
<ACTION>"}" {
    --actionCount;
    loc.step()
    if(!actionCount) {
        actionReturned = true;
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
        return yy::parser::make_ACTION_CODE(buffer_2, loc);
    }
    buffer_2 += '}';
}
<ACTION>\n buffer_2 += yytext[0] loc.lines(yyleng); loc.step();
<ACTION>. buffer_2 += yytext[0]; loc.step();

<TYPE>"<" ++typeCount; buffer_2 += '}'; loc.step();
<TYPE>">" {
    --typeCount;
    loc.step();
    if(!typeCount) {
        typeReturned = true;
        BEGIN(INITIAL);
        return yy::parser::make_TYPE_CODE(loc);
    }
    buffer_2 += '>';
}
<TYPE>\n buffer_2 += yytext[0]; loc.lines(yyleng); loc.step();
<TYPE>. buffer_2 += yytext[0]; loc.step();

%%

void driver::scanBegin() {
    yy_flex_debug = traceScanning;
    if(file.empty() || file == "-") {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(!(yyin = fopen(file.c_str(), "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void driver::scanEnd() {
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `YY_USER_INIT` macro to inject code that executes the first time `yylex()` is called. This is a flex macro supported by [RE-flex](https://github.com/Genivia/RE-flex) In addition, RE-flex has a new code section `%begin{ ... }` specifically for this purpose to define code that should be executed before scanning starts, but after the scanner is initialized (i.e. at the same spot as flex `YY_USER_INIT`). See the [Lexer/yyFlexLexer class](https://www.genivia.com/doc/reflex/html/index.html#reflex-lexer) structure in RE-flex to quickly understand what the generated scanner's code structure will look like.

There are also definitions for [initial code blocks](https://www.genivia.com/doc/reflex/html/index.html#reflex-code-blocks) in flex and RE-flex, which are executed in `yylex()` just before a pattern is matched.